# What units does ST_DISTANCE return?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, geospatial

In Cosmos DB, what is the units for the value returned by the `ST_DISTANCE` function? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial) are unhelpful in this regard:

> Returns the distance between the two GeoJSON Point, Polygon, or LineString expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,I did not find any official statements for the exact units by the `ST_DISTANCE` function in the documents as same as you. But I use the example in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#querying-spatial-types) to test with sql query.

***SQL:***

[image]

And I calculate the distance between the two coordinates with [online tool](http://boulter.com/gps/distance/).

[image]

Based on the results of test, I think the unit of the function is meter.Of course, you could commit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to verify the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

refer this official doc from MS in which they have mentioned it as in meters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-st-distance

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)